# css not fully applying to php function

Tags: php, css, function

What I'm trying to do is the following:
I have multiple folders with pictures. the previous page sends a different $_GET variable depending on which link is clicked, then the if statement takes that variable and runs the function to search for all the pictures and display them, then I use css to style the content. and that's it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/featuredCSS.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/indexCSS.css"/>
  <?php
```

just the header

```
    include("header.php");
```

my array, I only have two entries now, but it'll have more than 20

```
    $file_dir = array("img/houses/lux_/lux_1/*.*", 
              "img/houses/lux_/lux_2/*.*");
```

and the function. It took me a while to figure out how to make it do everything but I got it :)

```
    function PicLoads($file_dir){
      $files = glob($file_dir); 
      for ($i=1; $i<count($files); ++$i) { 
         $num = $files[$i]; 
         echo '<div id="images"><img id="image'.$i.'"src="'.$num.'"/></div>';

       echo '<div id="slider">';

                $b=1;
                do {
                    echo '<a href="#image'.$b.'">'.$b.'</a>';
                    ++$b;
                } while ($b < $i);

        echo '</div>';
      }
    }

?>

</head>
<body>
<div class="content-warp">
```

And the if() statement that calls the function.

```
    <?php if($_GET["house"] == "lux_1"){PicLoads($file_dir[1]);}?>


        </div>

</body>
<!--<?php include("footer.php"); ?>-->
</html>
```

very simple... the problem is that the styling is not being applied completely. here is the css:

```
.content-warp {
    position: absolute;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}
#images {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#images img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -400px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: all linear 500ms;
    -o-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 500ms;
}
#images img:target {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    opacity: 1;
}
#images img:first-child {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
#slider a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #70c6d1;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 200px;
}
#slider a:hover {
    background: #55b5f0;
}
```

The only thing that applies is the round corners.

SO my question is, how can I make the css completely apply to the html being made by the php function?

UPDATE:

This is what I had before, no function. 
The problem was that if I do it like this I'd have to sit there and manually type all of this like 70-something times. each time with different parameters.... that's alot

```
    <?php if($_GET["house"] == "lux_1"){ ?>
        <div id="images">
            <?php
                $files = glob("img/houses/lux_/lux_1/*.*"); 
                for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
                    $num = $files[$i]; 
                    echo '<img id="image'.$i.'"src="'.$num.'" alt="">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
                }
            ?> 
        </div>

        <div id="slider">
            <?php 
                $b=1;
                do {
                    echo '<a href="#image'.$b.'">'.$b.'</a>';
                    ++$b;
                } while ($b < $i);
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I checked your link and transition `(#images img)` seems to be parsed ok in firebug.

Comment: just added the nav buttons for the images. it repeats them over and over again. I think my sintax is correct... so lost

Comment: I can avoid the repeating of the nav buttons by placing them outside of the for loop. figured that out :)

Comment: @vlzvl yes, i'm uploading the change i made right now

Comment: if you scroll to the bottom of the page the nav buttons are there

Comment: You are rendering the navigation in your `<head>` tag :) Change that by rendering it in the `<body>`

Comment: I did. it didn't change anything.

Comment: No you didnt, your navigation is still outside its proper place. Put it inside `<body>`

Comment: the <nav> tags are part of the header and it loads from the include("header.php");
sorry f I confused you. 
<div id="slidder"> is the navigation for the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong! :D

UPDATED CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>b-International</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/featuredCSS.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/indexCSS.css"/>

<?php 
    include("header.php");
    $file_dir = array("img/houses/lux_/lux_1/*.*", 
              "img/houses/lux_/lux_2/*.*");

    function PicLoads($file_dir){
        $files = glob($file_dir);
```

made $i a global variable to use in two functions

```
        global $i;
```

and changed this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); ++$i) { 
     $num = $files[$i]; 
     echo '<div id="images"><img id="image'.$i.'"src="'.$num.'"/></div>';

   echo '<div id="slider">';

            $b=1;
            do {
                echo '<a href="#image'.$b.'">'.$b.'</a>';
                ++$b;
            } while ($b < $i);

    echo '</div>';
  }
```

to this:

```
        for ($i=1; $i<count($files); ++$i) { 
            $num = $files[$i]; 
            echo '<img id="image'.$i.'"src="'.$num.'"/>';
        }
    }//end PicLoads
```

added the function for the little nav buttons at the bottom

```
    function slide(){
        global $i;
        echo '<div id="slider">';
        $b=1;
        do {
            echo '<a href="#image'.$b.'">'.$b.'</a>';
            ++$b;} while ($b < $i);
        echo '</div>';
    }//end slide
?>


</head>
<body>

<div class="content-warp">
```

and changed the if() statement from this:

```
<?php if($_GET["house"] == "lux_1"){PicLoads($file_dir[1]);}?>
```

to this:

```
    <?php if($_GET["house"] == "lux_1"){ 
        echo '<div id="images">';    
        PicLoads($file_dir[1]);
        echo '</div>';
    }

    ?>
slide();
        </div>
```

and the end! xD

```
</body>
<!--<?php include("footer.php"); ?>-->
</html>
```

the reason why it kept loading the images one under the other was because `<div id="images">` was inside the for{} loop.

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your content is not in body part, so try to put it in `<Body>` Tag

I mean this part :

```
<?php    

    include("header.php"); 


    $file_dir = array("img/houses/lux_/lux_1/*.*", 
              "img/houses/lux_/lux_2/*.*");

    function PicLoads($file_dir){
      $files = glob($file_dir); 
      for ($i=1; $i<count($files); ++$i) { 
         $num = $files[$i]; 
         echo '<div id="images"><img id="image'.$i.'"src="'.$num.'"/></div>';
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: i'll try it. but would it matter? since it's just a function and all, and it's being called form within <body>?

Comment: tryed it, made no difference :(

Comment: Yes because you can't put your body content in head tag. Body is the main part of any browser where everything display well otherwise you can write anywhere but will not work exactly. This is the problem you are getting.

Comment: can you upload screenshot ? or link where it is running ?

Comment: @Mandeep Gill, if you look closely the rendering function is executed properly inside a `<body>`. It is just the function you're looking at.

Comment: wont let me upload a pic :(. i'll upload to a test server and post the link

Comment: but he also included header.php in head tag, don't know what is in header ?

Comment: So how you want to display images ? as i seen all css code is working but maybe you want to show images as inline ? do you ?

Comment: the overflow is supposed to be hidden. I just noticed I removed the nav buttons from the code, i'll add them on there.

Comment: yes navigation is working and everything else but i think you want to display content in other style.